# I can't install any github project with Pip

Tags: python, git, github, cmd, pip

I've had to reinstall a lot of libraries on Windows.  When I want to install pycdc from github

Installing pycdc on windows.

pip install git+https://github.com/zrax/pycdc.git

I get:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\TT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ashu2b4z-build\setup.py

```
C:\Users\TT\unroll>pycdc .py
'pycdc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\TT\unroll>pip install git+https://github.com/zrax/pycdc.git
Collecting git+https://github.com/zrax/pycdc.git
  Cloning https://github.com/zrax/pycdc.git to c:\users\TT\appdata\local\temp\pip-ashu2b4z-build
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\TT\Anaconda3\lib\tokenize.py", line 452, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\TT\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-ashu2b4z-build\\setup.py'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\TT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ashu2b4z-build\

C:\Users\TT\unroll>pip install git+https://github.com/zrax/pycdc.git
```

I feel like I'm missing some dependency files

Boy do I  ever regret doing a re-install. python may be nice to use but a nightmare to setup

Also:

```
C:\Users\TT>pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/BlahCo/search/tree/prod_release_branch/ProductName
Collecting git+ssh://git@github.com/BlahCo/search/tree/prod_release_branch/ProductName
  Cloning ssh://git@github.com/BlahCo/search/tree/prod_release_branch/ProductName to c:\users\TT\appdata\local\temp\pip-6x2kywme-build
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.255.113)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? y
Please type 'yes' or 'no': yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.255.113' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights

Command "git clone -q ssh://git@github.com/BlahCo/search/tree/prod_release_branch/ProductName C:\Users\TT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-6x2kywme-build" failed with error code 128 in None
```

Comment: What is with the space between `pycdc` and  `.py` ? The very standard _'pycdc' is not recognized as an internal or external command_ windows command error tells you this very nicely, so logic should tell you that it should be `pycdc.py`. Secondly, Your pip command gives an error that `C:\\Users\\TT\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-ashu2b4z-build\\setup.py` cannot be found, did you verify that you files actually exist in this location?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Not sure what you mean, but I can't get: pip install -U git+https://github.com/zrax/pycdc or.zip variation to work

Comment: what I mean is, does `setup.py` exist in `C:\Users\TT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ashu2b4z-build` ?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Don't think so.

Comment: that is a problem, why do you not check? It is expected there, so perhaps your app does not extract the files as expected.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Same issues on a virtual box fresh install.  Maybe the path is incorrect or deregistered.  Haven't removed it.  This is bizzare

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Admins right issue maybe?

Comment: I feel like this is one of those issues that takes 4 days to fix

Comment: could very well be admin right issues. Generally admin rights are required to do installations. Can the user you are attempting to install as access that path?

Comment: `pycdc` is not a python package. It makes no sense to install it with `pip`

Comment: @olricson I found that it occurred with all github files.  I reinstalled my pc, and that fixed 99% of issues occurring.  I think there might still be issues I'll verify and confirm, but a fresh system clean and reinstall did wonders :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're facing two different issues.
First, for pycdc:
Pycdc does not seems to be a python package so it does make sense to install it with pip (but it's logical that the `setup.py` was not found)
Checking there github (https://github.com/zrax/pycdc) it appears you need to download there source and build it.

Second, BlahCo:
You're trying to install it downloading there sources via `ssh` instead of `https` (like you tried with pycdc). If you try to use `ssh`, you'll need to configure your github account with your ssh public key. 
The error `git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)` shows that you did not configure your account correctly
For more details see: https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/

Comment: I'm aware of the issues but how do I fix.  This issue is present for any and all github stuff on windows (even in a fresh re-installed pc)

Answer (score 0):

In your requirements, add the URL with a Personal Token to the github repo.

```
munch
pprint
coloredlogs
git+https://104360bcf4d8a00198bd355d73110ba75866c3e8:@github.company.com/kubernetes-paas/paas-shared-modules.git@master
```

Installing will use the https API instead of ssh, since you can't provide the keys.

```
$ pip3 install -r requirements.txt
Collecting git+https://104360bcf4d8a00198bd355d73110ba75866c3e8:@github.company.com/kubernetes-paas/paas-shared-modules.git@master (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
  Cloning https://104360bcf4d8a00198bd355d73110ba75866c3e8:@github.company.com/kubernetes-paas/paas-shared-modules.git (to master) to /private/var/folders/c8/p20lpvwn1kl7cyk7b282s3x1j2r82f/T/pip-2py7sl6t-build
```