# import python module from github to jupyter notebook

Tags: python, git, github, jupyter-notebook

WHAT am I doing wrong?

This doesn't help: [Installing module from GitHub through Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44873473/installing-module-from-github-through-jupyter-notebook)

I just want to import this python module.  Just the one.  It's at

http://github.com/peterroelants/peterroelants.github.io/tree/master/notebooks/gaussian_process/rational_quadratic.py

```
!pip install git+http://github.com/peterroelants/peterroelants.github.io/tree/master/notebooks/gaussian_process/rational_quadratic.git



​

Collecting git+http://github.com/peterroelants/peterroelants.github.io/tree/master/notebooks/gaussian_process/rational_quadratic.git
  Cloning http://github.com/peterroelants/peterroelants.github.io/tree/master/notebooks/gaussian_process/rational_quadratic.git to /private/var/folders/xq/0txkbk490zl1y5wp5vd3bhhnpw3bp9/T/pip-req-build-pzltmobn
  Running command git clone -q http://github.com/peterroelants/peterroelants.github.io/tree/master/notebooks/gaussian_process/rational_quadratic.git /private/var/folders/xq/0txkbk490zl1y5wp5vd3bhhnpw3bp9/T/pip-req-build-pzltmobn
  fatal: repository 'http://github.com/peterroelants/peterroelants.github.io/tree/master/notebooks/gaussian_process/rational_quadratic.git/' not found
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q http://github.com/peterroelants/peterroelants.github.io/tree/master/notebooks/gaussian_process/rational_quadratic.git /private/var/folders/xq/0txkbk490zl1y5wp5vd3bhhnpw3bp9/T/pip-req-build-pzltmobn Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1):

You would usually clone the root repository including all the files, but also the repository does not seem to be a Python Package. The reason you are getting the error is because `pip` works through `PyPi` which hosts all the python packages, and the mentioned repository is not hosted on there. However, in your case you could just clone the repository or copy,download the `rational_quadratic.py` to your project directory and import the module.
 [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47411740/i-cant-install-any-github-project-with-pip) may be able to help.

Comment: "*pip works through PyPi*" That's not exactly true. `pip` looks at PyPI when asked to install a package **by name** (`pip install numpy`). But it can install packages from URLs. In the case of the OP the URL points to a branch at Github (which is an error — the URL must point to the root of the repo + it's possible to select a commit, a tag or a branch) at a repository that's not a `pip`-installable package (which is an error 2 here). The rest of your answer is ok.

Comment: I agree, I'll be careful of my answers in the future. Thanks for the comment!